# How would you add data to a data store from a form in EXTJS 4?

Tags: extjs4, datastore

Is there a way to add data into a data store from a textfield based form?

for example:

```
    Name:______
    Team:______
    Number:_____
    Age:_______
```

when submitted injects into the data store?

Comment: Have even looked at the **[examples](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example)**?

Comment: I'd rather participate in a community that I support- Stack Overflow, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form.updateRecord() and then store.add(record).

But what you should really do is look at the examples that ship with ExtJS. There are lots of great ideas on how to do most things you need.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!  I was really just looking for a starting spot to research.  You nailed it.